# How to call a macro from a macro initiated in a dropdown?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dropdown with four options in the first worksheet of my workbook. This workbook is named SOW.

When any of the options are clicked, a macro is run. Each of these four macros call several other macros. The issue is that some called macros aren't working.

One macro selected from the dropdown is called `Sub Project_With_Discounts()`.
This macro calls five other macros `Sub UnhideDiscountColumn()`, `Sub MakeManagementFee10()`, `Sub UnhideTermsAndConditions()`, `Sub HideStepanColumns ()`, and `Sub UnhideTotalDiscount()`.
None of these called macros are working.

I am working on a Macbook Air.

I temporarily created a button and assigned each macro to it one at a time. The macros work individually.

```vb
Sub Project_With_Discounts()
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Call UnhideDiscountColumn
    Call MakeManagementFee10
    Call UnhideTotalDiscount
    Call UnhideTermsAndConditions
    Call HideStepanColumn
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Sub UnhideDiscountColumn()
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Worksheets("THIRD-PARTY").Range("L:L").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Sub MakeManagementFee10()
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Sheets("THIRD-PARTY").Range("C26").Value2 = 0.1
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Sub UnhideTotalDiscount()
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Worksheets("SOW").Rows("708:708").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Sub UnhideTermsAndConditions()
    Sheets("SOW").Range("726:779").Rows.Hidden = False
End Sub

Sub HideStepanColumns()
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Sheets("THIRD-PARTY").Range("H:J").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
End Sub
```

I don't get any error messages.

Comment: step through your code see what is happening line by line

Comment: Also, why do you keep calling the various `Application` bits? AFAIK you can put them all in your top/first sub and it'll apply as it calls the others.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like there was a type-o that called one of the subroutines incorrectly. VBA is very unforgiving to typing error. Try what I have below.

I also added two more subroutines `TurnOffFunctions` & `TurnOnFunctions` to avoid redundancies your code had. I do this because it's easier to maintain, easier to call, and you can move it to other subs you have.

I tested the code and it seemed like everything worked fine. So please if this works for you mark it as the answer.

```
Sub Project_With_Discounts()
Call TurnOffFunctions
Call UnhideDiscountColumn
Call MakeManagementFee10
Call UnhideTotalDiscount
Call UnhideTermsAndConditions
Call HideStepanColumns 'This is the line that had the type error. It was missing the S
Call TurnOnFunctions
End Sub

Sub UnhideDiscountColumn()
Worksheets("THIRD-PARTY").Range("L:L").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End Sub

Sub MakeManagementFee10()
Sheets("THIRD-PARTY").Range("C26").Value2 = 0.1
End Sub

Sub UnhideTotalDiscount()
Worksheets("SOW").Rows("708:708").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End Sub

Sub UnhideTermsAndConditions()
Sheets("SOW").Range("726:779").Rows.Hidden = False
End Sub

Sub HideStepanColumns()
Sheets("THIRD-PARTY").Range("H:J").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End Sub

Sub TurnOffFunctions()

Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

End Sub

Sub TurnOnFunctions()

Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You also might benefit from marking the subs getting called as `Private Sub`, that way under the Macro selection in the Developer tab of the ribbon they don't show up and will remain hidden.

Comment: Hey @Mark S. I appreciate your response and advice about the subroutines (TurnOffFunctions and TurnOnFunctions). I made the changes you recommended but it still isn't working for some reason. I checked and none of the 5 calls for the Project_With_Discounts are working. They still work individually though so that and your advice not working has me quite confused. I think it must be something to do with the Project_With_Discounts sub since the 5 subs getting called work by themselves but again, I'm not a seasoned macro user yet. Working on a Macbook definitely has nothing to do with it?

Comment: I'm unsure if it's because you're on mac, but double check to make sure the tab references are valid, meaning the tab names haven't changed because that's the only actual reference I can see having an issue. as a refresher the tab names I see which are case sensitive are "THIRD-PARTY" & "SOW"

Comment: Did you check the tab names and ensure that wasn't the issue?